# Is there a Ansible "not" tag for roles available?

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a short way to not execute specific tags that are listed in my playbook.yml. Example:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - base
    - webdev
  roles_not:
    - temp_disabled
```

The problem in my case is, webdev contains a lot of sites and I would like to add just something like `temp_disabled` instead of changing all tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide `--skip-tags "temp_disabled"` on the command line to skip the **tag** `temp_disabled`. You can not skip roles but it's simple to tag all roles with the same tag as the role name.

Comment: Works perfectly. I've just discovered that this works fine with vagrant. ```ansible.skip_tags``` -> http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old, but I stumbled across this looking for the same answer. `--skip-tags` won't work in my situation (the tags I can use are limited).

I ended up using this:

```
when: "'temp_disabled' not in ansible_run_tags"
```